# posttype and custom fields on multisite

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, multisite, advanced-custom-fields

is there a plugin to create custom post types and custom fields on the main network itself so that its available across all the sites in that network and can be accessed by all sites in that networks...for single site we use `advanced custom field` and `simple post type` is there anything for multi-site too? plz don't say `Multisite Post Duplicator` as it creates a copy of the post type custom fields etc for each site in the network...that way the database would become too huge with multiple copies.

Comment: Note that databases can handle millions of entries, the problem with large databases is not so much that they're large, but that people write themes with awful queries, asking for things that are expensive to query for, e.g. show me everything except X Y and Z, or show me all posts with a post meta equal to A B or C

Comment: This can be done. But first thing first, `all sites on WordPress multisite do not share any post types table`. So what you can do is create the table/logic on the main site, then use filters and actions to extend the contents to other sites. 

So for example, to display the post type on other sites, you can check once the post view screen is active on the admin, so instead of fetching on site-specific tables, you fetch directly from the table and vice versa.

So on other sites just fetch and apply whatever actions you want, but you only have one table which is located on the main site.

Answer (score 1):

All websites in the multisite are independent and have own database tables, and they can have own plugins and own post types. Post types need to be registered on each site in the multisite, and posts have to be in the database tables for each site. There is no content on the network level that all sites can share directly.